# How to remove gnome on Ubuntu20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I'm using Ubuntu20.04

I used the command `sudo apt-get install gnome` by mistake and gnome package was installed on my system, how to restore everything to its original state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just tested `sudo apt-get install gnome` and then `sudo apt-get purge gnome --autoremove` on a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. It does not remove all of the dependencies which are dragged in by installing `gnome` because many of them are suggested by other installed packages.

Fortunately, on Ubuntu, apt keeps a log of what packages were installed and when. To see the log, it is enough to issue:

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

There you will find the list of packages grouped by install occurrence. Look for `Commandline: apt-get install gnome`. If you did not install or upgrade recently, it should be the last one.

To copy the list of packages for removal, you will want to pre-format them to strip the information in parentheses. You can do it with [this useful script](https://askubuntu.com/a/176250/1112981):

```
$ perl -pe 's/\(.*?\)(, )?//g' /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Then just copy the list of packages installed with `gnome` to your `sudo apt purge` command.

Answer (score 4):

Run the following command in bash shell

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome*
```

This will remove the every package in configuration file of gnome.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome
```

should remove everything co-installed if you haven't changed the defaults.

Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/247549/is-it-possible-to-undo-an-apt-get-install-command

Answer (score -1):

You can't. But you can install another Desktop environment like `apt-get install lxde` and select that one from the login screen drop down box.